# How to generate a contract's artifact in solidity/foundry to use with targetArtifact?

Tags: abi, foundry

Foundry [invariant tests](https://book.getfoundry.sh/forge/invariant-testing#invariant-test-helper-functions) (stateful fuzzing) have helper functions for configurable invariant test setup such as `targetArtifact(string memory newTargetedArtifact_)`, which adds a `Target Artifact` defined as:

```
The desired ABI to be used for a given contract. These can be used for proxy contract configurations.
```

In order to add this artifact, solidity must have generated this artifact or abi. What is an example of generating such an ABI?

Answer (score 1):

To generate an ABI for a Solidity contract, you can use the Solidity compiler (solc) which can output the contract's ABI in JSON format.

For example, let's say you have a Solidity contract named MyContract defined in a file named MyContract.sol. You can generate the ABI for this contract using the following command in the terminal:

```
solc --abi MyContract.sol -o build
```

This command will generate the ABI in JSON format and save it in a file named MyContract.abi inside the build directory.

Once you have the ABI file, you can use it to interact with the contract using web3.js or other Ethereum development tools.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Right, but how would I use this with `targetArtifact`?